# com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot start native grabber

Tags: java, jquery, webcam

Here I have written some code to capture the image from USBcam using java.

**Below is the code:**

```
Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.open();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(webcam.getImage(), "PNG", new File("d:/hello-world1.png"));
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And I have added 3 jars what ever required,
but when running the application, image is not getting,
Exception is raised.

**Below is the Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:57)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:120)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamTask.process(WebcamTask.java:35)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.cgt.WebcamOpenTask.open(WebcamOpenTask.java:20)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.open(Webcam.java:187)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.open(Webcam.java:147)
    at ImageCapture.main(ImageCapture.java:16)
Caused by: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot start native grabber!
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDevice.open(WebcamDefaultDevice.java:220)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.cgt.WebcamOpenTask.handle(WebcamOpenTask.java:38)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.run(WebcamProcessor.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please suggest me any idea where am putting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code, the message `Cannot start native grabber` is raised if `grabber.openSession(...)` returns `false` where `grabber=new OpenIMAJGrabber();` which is a native `Bridj` proxy. This catch makes diagnosing difficult, as the real exception is hidden. There seems to be a native library access problem, so you should check if the `.so` or the `.dll` is indeed in your classpath. You should consider debugging to see if `grabber` is well instantiated...